# Laravel Blade - @extends from a html string - Is it possible?

Tags: laravel, view, laravel-blade

I wonder if we can `@extends` from a HTML string..

Usually we use `@extends` and insert a view name as the parameter (`@extends('template.master')`)

But what I want to achieve this times is `@extends('<html><body>@yield('content')</body></html>')`...

You know what I mean, right?

Hope somebody can help me... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Depends on Laravel documentation `@extends` directive to specify which layout the child view should "inherit". it means that `@extends` designed to take a path of view that i will inherit from. You can get more information from: [extending-a-layout](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/blade#extending-a-layout)

Comment: but can we make our own directive which copy the `@extends` directive, but take `html string` as input instead of `a path`.... do you think we can achieve that?

Comment: well i think we can achieve that, however i see that no need to do that because `extends`is good way do achieve inheritance.

Comment: i have my own reason why i want to do that.... it is hard to explain... but i really need to amend `@extends` directive to be working with `html string` instead of `a path`...